# Styling Multiple MVC Views

Tags: xslt, asp.net-mvc-4

We are developing a back-end system to provide core functionality of making hotel booking reservations, in ASP.NET MVC 4.

We need to grant the graphical designers the ability to style the booking page(s), look, feel and layout.  We'd rather them not have direct access to the source code (mvc views).

We are considering using XSL, but can or does anyone have any other recommendations ?

Comment: Why not just throw a bunch of classes and ids on this where appropriate? If you do that properly (which really shouldn't be a problem) that should solve the problem, right?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, can you elaborate a bit more ?